# Gif output not as smooth when selecting a sequence of files individually

Tags: conversion, imagemagick

I have a sequence of images `001.png` `002.png` `003.png` that I would like to combine into an animation.

I used the following command

```
convert -dispose 3 -loop 0 *.png out.gif
```

And it looks ok. However, when I tried this

```
convert -dispose 3 -loop 0 "001.png" "002.png" "003.png" out2.gif
```

out2.gif was not as "smooth" as out.gif.

Why is there a difference in the output between the two commands, which seem to mean the same thing?

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using? I tried with 6.6.0-1 and obtained the same result with both commands in terms of smoothness. I also compared the resulting gifs: they are byte-to-byte identical.

Comment: @Andrea I am using 6.8.6-8